# MYSQL large data table setup

Tags: mysql, large-data

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `levels` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `creator` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `levelcode` longtext NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `views` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `favCount` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `total_votes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` float(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `spamCount` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Basicly I have created a game where people can submit their own levels. What I am currently debating is whether or not to move the levelcode column into its own table, or even each level in its own textfile.  Levelcode can get fairly large(500,000+ characters)

have any advice?

Comment: "500,000+" is only 500KB. That won't probably hurt your DB ... if your smart enough to avoid unneeded `SELECT *`...

Comment: I am VERY careful with my select statements, thanks for the tip though.
update: just did a database scan. the largest level is 4,766,887 characters

Answer (score 0):

The longtext should be fine for you. From the documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

```
LONGTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]

A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 – 1) characters.
The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multi-byte characters.
The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the configured
maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and available memory. Each
LONGTEXT value is stored using a 4-byte length prefix that indicates the number
of bytes in the value.
```

Edit: I believe the packet size mentioned is the MySQL packet size, which is 16MB by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can have LongText in your case as the limit for Longtext is

```
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT       L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32   (4 Gigabytes)
```

Check out this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

Comment: alright, so there would be no improve performance if it was in its own table? -- I just double checked... the largest level is 4,766,887 characters.